# xamarin EventHandler is always null

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a code which should notify a delegate in one of service classes on receiving an event:

```
    public class TestClass : ParentClass
    {
        public event EventHandler<string> MyDelegate;

        public override void OnAction(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var handler = MyDelegate;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, "test");
            }
        }
    }
```

I instantiate it by:

```
    private TestClass mytest= new TestClass ();
```

And then assign it in one of the functions:

```
    mytest.MyDelegate+= (sender, info) => {
    };
```

The delegate never gets called. I have stepped through with debugger and I see that delegate is being assigned, but the check inside a class is always null... Cant figure out whats the problem...

Comment: how about assign it in the constructor - chances are your order of execution is not correct

Comment: @StenPetrov oh.. you mean if I do an assignment after creating an object, it will not work?

Comment: put a breakpoint on your `mytest.MyDelegate += ...` and inside `OnAction` - see what gets hit first

Comment: @StenPetrov I did - first hit is mytest.MyDelegate += ... and then an action which tests it in a class

Comment: Then make sure you're hitting the same instance. Add debug output for `mytest.GetHashCode()` and `this.GetHashCode()` in `OnAction`

Comment: @StenPetrov you are right, hashes dont match.. hmm, checking...

Comment: @StenPetrov how is it possible with an only instance?..

Comment: well... it's obviously not the only instance. Make explicit parameterless constructors in `TestClass` and `ParentClass`, add debug output for the hash in each, then set a breakpoint in these ctors and look at the call stack to see who's creating the other instance

Comment: @StenPetrov thanks Sten, it appears I had an instance created statically by android and then created another dynamically, and the first was actually firing.. thanx for your kind input

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an execution order issue. What could be happening is that `OnAction` within `TestClass` is being called before the delegate hookup. Try the following:

```
public class TestClass : ParentClass
{
    public event EventHandler<string> MyDelegate;

    public class TestClass(Action<string> myAction)
    {
      MyDelegate += myAction;
    }

    public override void OnAction(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var handler = MyDelegate;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, "test");
        }
    }
}
```

Just pass the delegate through the constructor, this should make sure its hooked up before any calls to `OnAction()`

You can pass through the handler in a couple ways:

1.) As an anonymous method:

```
private TestClass mytest= new TestClass ((sender, info) => { Console.WriteLine("Event Attached!") });
```

2.) Pass in the method group:

```
public class MyEventHandler(object sender, string e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Event Attached!");
}

private TestClass mytest= new TestClass(MyEventHandler);
```

I generally recommend the second way as it allows you to unhook the handler and do clean up once you are done with it:

```
myTest.MyDelegate -= MyEventHandler;
```

Comment: How do I instantiate an EventHandler to pass it to constructor?